# Continuity in terms of interior

Tags: general-topology

I have encountered definitions of continuity using closure and preimages. I was wondering if we can also talk about continuity using the interior, that is, a map $f \colon A \to B$ is continuous if and only if $A \subset int(B)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $(A,\tau)$ and $(B,\mu)$ are different topological spaces, then it may not be that a continuous mapping implies that $A\subseteq Int(B)$.

For example, let $(A,\tau)=(\mathbb{R},\tau_{disc}) $ and $(B,\mu)=(\mathbb{N},\mu_{ind.})$ where $\tau_{disc}$ is the discrete topology on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mu_{ind.}$ is the indiscrete topology on $\mathbb{N}$. If $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ is any mapping, it will trivially be continuous. But $Int(\mathbb{N})=\mathbb{N}$ in $(\mathbb{N}, \mu_{ind.})$ and clearly, $\mathbb{R}$ is not a subset of $\mathbb{N}$.

Edit: From looking at other comments, you may be referring to continuity in a metric space and not a more general topological space. A tip would be to tab this question under metric spaces if that's the case